# netbeans unable to find java.lang no jdk9

Tags: java, netbeans, java-9

I've been trying to install the new Netbeans (8.1) on jdk 9. But netbeans can't find java.lang . I checked java platform and saw this: 
[image]

the followings were added as my "platform sources" :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0\jrt-fs.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0\src.zip
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0\javafx-src.zip
```

but i'm getting this error and can't get it work:

```
cannot access java.lang
  Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

1. Open your Project Tab
2. Right Click on Libraries
3. Select Properties. Project Properties will displayed.
4. on Categories Tab select Source
5. Set Source/Binary Format to JDK9

this is my Project Properties, but I used JDK8
[image: My Project Properties]

Answer (score 1):

Update: Netbeans nightly builds now support JDK9 !
see http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDK9Support

So download: http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/